# Git multiple releases workflow

Tags: git, github

As a team we work on multiple releases at once (release-1, 2 and 3).
Each release has its own commits and features but we keep frequently updating release-2 with whatever is in release-1. We then update release-3 with whatever is in release-2. This way we keep any release branch after first up to date.

This workflow has worked for a quite a long time but recently release-1 started containing release-2 and release-3 code out of nowhere. We've checked all the commits and they are correctly committed towards the right release branch.

A while ago we've noticed that even though GitHub clearly states that we merge release-1 into release-2, it does the exact opposite... We've merged release-2 into release-1...

[image]

Is there any reason you've come across of why this could have happened? We are trying to get our heads around it and have no idea what has caused it. Any suggestions will help.

We've excluded a possibility of someone pulling the wrong release branch into their local branch and then pushing it to the release branch...

Comment: There is no way that git does this automatically without you telling it. Go through the commit point where `release-2` is merged into `release-1` and you will be able find out who has done it.

Comment: As you say, the PR clearly states that `release-1` is merged into `release-2`. The offending merge commit is somewhere in your history. You will need to find it to figure out what happened and, more importantly, determine how to fix it.